# How to transfer data from NSArray to String in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have to put data in tableview, but even tough I get info from JSON, I can't pass data to postTitle variable. Why is that? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource {

var postTitle = [AnyObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var baseURL = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json"

    //        https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/9324191.json

    if let url = NSURL(string: baseURL) {
        var taskURL = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                var jsonError: NSError?
                if let topStories = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as? NSArray {

                        self.postTitle.append(topStories)

                }


            }

        })


        taskURL.resume()

    }


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    println(postTitle.count)
    return postTitle.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    println(self.postTitle)
  //  cell.textLabel?.text = postTitle[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: Are you aware that `dataTaskWithURL()` works **asynchronously**? – See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782932/tableview-is-not-updating-until-i-tap-another-tab-and-get-back-swift, or search for "get value from asynchronous function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the other guy from Reddit help me out. I was missing few things. First was data type Int, which needs to be passed to instance variable, and second was UITableView: here is working solution. Hope this will help someone.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
var postTitles = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var baseURL = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json"


    if let url = NSURL(string: baseURL) {
        var taskURL = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                var jsonError: NSError?
                if let topStories = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as? [Int] {
                        self.postTitles = Array(topStories[0...9])

                        // Reload the table with our new results!
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        })

        taskURL.resume()

    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return postTitles.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell


    let postTitle = String(self.postTitles[indexPath.row])

    cell.textLabel?.text = postTitle

    return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`topStories` is an `NSArray`, but you are appending it to the `postTitle` array (which is of type `[AnyObject]`).  `Array.append` adds a single item to the array.  So you will have added one entry, an `NSArray` of a bunch of post IDs, to your `postTitle` array.

I am guessing what you want is to add the contents of `topStories` to `postTitle`?  In which case you want to use the `extend` rather than the `append` method:

```
self.postTitle.extend(topStories)
```

Comment: Or use the `+=` syntax: `self.postTitle += topStories`

Comment: The problem is that i have this function which return's me 0. And even if put what @Airspeed Velocity suggest.

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    println(postTitle.count)
    return postTitle.count
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Given that you apparently reload ALL the titles with each request, you could just as easily do this: `self.titles = topStories`

I just built a test app this way and it worked perfectly fine.

PS: `self.postTitle.append` would have yielded the wrong result anyway, as it would also append titles you already have in your array. The method you probably should be using would be `self.postTitle.join` as it uses intersection.

Comment: It didn't work. Nothing is stored in postTitle variable, but if i println(self.postTitles) after JSONSerialization, it stored values in that variable. I don't get it.

Comment: Here is the [gist of my working code](https://gist.github.com/Jan0707/b401441ee65c7a26f485)

Comment: i need to check it, i found other solution

Comment: Interested to know what your final solution is :-)

Comment: So the other guy from Reddit help me out. I was missing few things. First was data type Int, which needs to be passed to instance variable, and second was UITableView: here is working solution. Hope this will help someone.
``